Equilibrium equations of a rigid body in contact with elastic body

Consider a structure comprising an elastic deformable body (in pink) attached to a rigid body (in yellow) at the right side ( $\Gamma_c$ interface) and fixed at the left side.
Assume a force $F$ is applied to the rigid body at an angle $\beta$, as shown in the diagram. Subsequently, the deformable body undergoes deformation. (By the way, the elastic and rigid bodies stay together even when the force is removed)
What are the equilibrium conditions for the rigid body?
I think that it is expressed as follows:
In the x-direction: $ \sum F_x = - F \cos(\beta) + F_{\text{elastic}, x} = 0$
$ - F \cos(\beta) + \sigma \cdot \textbf{n} \cos(\beta) = 0$
In the y-direction: $\sum F_y = - F \sin(\beta) + F_{\text{elastic}, y} = 0$
$ - F \sin(\beta) + \sigma \cdot \textbf{n} \sin(\beta) = 0$
About a reference point: $\sum M = - F \cos(\beta) d +  \sigma \cdot \textbf{n} \cos(\beta) d= 0$
where
$\sigma$ is the stress of the elastic body and $d$ is the perpendicular distance from the forces causing moment to the reference point which is taken to be the bottom point of the left corner of the rigid body.
Note:

x-axis is taken as the horizontal axis and y-axis as the vertical axis.
the cantilever is allowed to deform and to rotate while staying attached to the rigid body.

I'd like to know whether the equations I wrote are correct?
